# Cannot find symbol Canvas

Tags: java

My class `Window` is the following

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;

public class Window extends Canavas {

    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

        frame.setPrefferedSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();
    }
}
```

I've imported the abstract window toolkit's `Canvass` class, so I can't understand why I receive the following errors:

> cannot find symbol Canvas
>
> cannot find symbol JFrame

Note that I am not using an IDE, I am using a text editor.

Comment: What about importing JFrame in your code and add the Canvas jar to javac ?

Comment: It looks like you made a typo, in your code you have `Canavas` instead of `Canvas`. Also, you need to add `import javax.swing.JFrame;`

Comment: @BrunoDM Thanks, that eliminated the no Canvas symbol error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is related to class importing.
You need to import all the classes that you use. There are just two exceptions to this:

- classes in the `java.lang` package
- classes in the same package as the current class

---

In your snippet the following classes are not imported:

- Game and Dimension (presumably these are in the same `com.tutorial.main` package)
- Canvas and JFrame. You misspelled Canvas as Canavas (this is where an IDE, or just a spellchecker, comes in), and did not import JFrame.

So the solution for your problem is:
Fix typo: `extends Canvas`
Add: `import javax.swing.JFrame;`